# Perspective property doesn't work on my SCSS

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm a beginner. I was writing HTML and SCCS, just copying the code which our teacher showed. He was adding some sentences and I followed one by one, checking if new codes effect as he suggested. I've been successful and the followings are HTML and SCSS at that time:

HTML

```
<div class="banner">
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
body {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
}

.banner {
    display: flex;
}
$width: 23px;
.panel {
    position: relative;
    width: $width;
    height: 110px;
  // border: 1px solid white;
   overflow: hidden;
   animation: rotate 6s infinite ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    from { transform: rotateX(0deg); }
    to { transform: rotateX(360deg);}
}

.panel::before {
    position: absolute;
    left: var(--left);
    content: 'Hello World';
    font-size: 96px;
    width: max-content;
    color: hsl(var(--hue), 75%, 75%);
}

@for $i from 0 to 24 {
    .panel:nth-child(#{$i + 1}) {
        --left: #{$width * $i * -1};
        --hue: #{360 / 24 * $i};
}
}
```

Then he added

```
perspective: 500px;
```

to body in SCSS, like this:

```
    place-items: center;
    perspective: 500px;
```

What had appeared on his screen changed it's image immediately but nothing happened to
mine.
My computer runs on Windows 10, I tried to read "index.html" by Google Chrome, Microsoft Edge, Mozilla Firefox but
all unsuccessful.

I do want to  complete his 3D animation by myself.
Please help me.

Comment: I suggest you try it in codepen. I copied your code and it seems to work https://codepen.io/Mrwilson/pen/VwMryXj

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I saw the animation in your codepen.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I saw the animation in your codepen. The letter H in "Hello World..." keeps vertical during rotation,while when our teacher added "perspective", his letter H tilted. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NSWr6dkc_Xw&t=418s   16:00

Comment: In the description under the video are the 2 codepens from that lesson to look at

Comment: What do you mean by " 2 codepens "?   I don't know much about codepen.

Comment: https://codepen.io/kevinpowell/pen/abwqBxE

Comment: https://codepen.io/kevinpowell/pen/mdwXRqd

Comment: The point is my “perspective” didn’t work, your “perspective” didn’t work, but teacher’s worked.

Comment: The 2 links above are the links to your teachers code. Compare your code to his

Comment: For 2nd link, I have the same code.  For 1st link how did you get this?  I think the code of 1st link is that teacher added  "rotateX(720deg)" to @keyframes rotate about 17:30 video time. And please note animation in 1st link is different from that in YouTube. In 1st link, the letter H rotates vertically but in YouTube it rotates tilted.

Comment: I'm most interested in video time 16:00 when teacher added "perspective".  1st link's code has "perspective property" but it is ineffective?

Comment: i got the links on your teachers video. Scroll down and click "Show More" There are 2 CodePen links

Answer (score 1):

add the `perspective: 500px;` to `.banner` class

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added the 
```perspective: 500px; ``` to ```.banner ``` class and it worked.Then I  added several sentences, some of them worked well and final result was rather different from the target which  teacher showed.Last night I moved 
```perspective: 500px; ``` and 
```perspective-origin:; ``` from ```.banner ``` to ```body ```. Then everything went well,this is the YouTube  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NSWr6dkc_Xw&t=418s

Still I do want to know why his addition works?

Comment: sanma if his answer worked for you, you must click the checkmark next to his answer to indicate his was the correct answer

Comment: His answer didn't work.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? `perspective` create only 3D space. if perspective not define `translateZ()` not working on your code.

Comment: I want to make up this one step by step:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NdftnCDwKaU&t=244s  In this video when Amit adds "perspective" 10:26,result becomes perspective. But when I try this, nothing happens. So stopping here I cannot go further.

Comment: Sorry I don't know.